# Appending sections of a file into duplicates of a previously written file

Tags: python

I have a file that deposited 10 sections of data into a single file (lets call these files `10S`). Normally, each section would get its separate file. I want to append each section to another file, but I need to make 10 duplicates of this previously written file (one duplicate for each section of data). I'm trying to do this over a directory of 24 different `10S` files. Each section of data starts with a `MODEL` number and ends at `ENDMDL`. The `10S` files have the following format:

```
MODEL 1
HETATM    1    N LIG L   2     103.724 127.482 115.429  1.00  1.00           N  
HETATM    2    C LIG L   2     104.244 126.274 114.627  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    3    C LIG L   2     104.270 124.877 115.271  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    4    C LIG L   2     104.790 123.669 114.469  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    5    C LIG L   2     106.049 122.916 114.940  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    6    O LIG L   2     105.991 121.396 115.179  1.00  1.00           O  
HETATM    7    O LIG L   2     107.364 123.683 115.170  1.00  1.00           O  
HETATM    8    H LIG L   2     103.707 128.376 115.017  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM    9    H LIG L   2     103.409 127.360 116.354  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   10    H LIG L   2     104.574 126.402 113.658  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   11    H LIG L   2     103.940 124.749 116.241  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   12    H LIG L   2     104.992 124.020 113.479  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   13    H LIG L   2     104.012 122.944 114.585  1.00  1.00           H  
ENDMDL
MODEL 2
HETATM    1    N LIG L   2     103.717 127.477 115.429  1.00  1.00           N  
HETATM    2    C LIG L   2     104.273 126.292 114.619  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    3    C LIG L   2     104.255 124.874 115.217  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    4    C LIG L   2     104.812 123.689 114.407  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    5    C LIG L   2     106.038 122.911 114.921  1.00  1.00           C  
HETATM    6    O LIG L   2     107.364 123.649 115.179  1.00  1.00           O  
HETATM    7    O LIG L   2     105.936 121.396 115.178  1.00  1.00           O  
HETATM    8    H LIG L   2     103.728 128.384 115.046  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM    9    H LIG L   2     103.349 127.328 116.331  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   10    H LIG L   2     104.658 126.448 113.674  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   11    H LIG L   2     103.870 124.718 116.162  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   12    H LIG L   2     105.071 124.069 113.441  1.00  1.00           H  
HETATM   13    H LIG L   2     104.024 122.966 114.456  1.00  1.00           H  
ENDMDL
```

The code I've made so far has managed to append every single `10S` section to a single file using `enumerate()` on the line number containing `ENDMDL`, but I would need 240 or so duplicate files, not a single file with everything compiled into it. Here is what I have so far:

```
import os

path ="C:\\Users\\Family\\Desktop\\School Junk\\GABA Project\\GABA Structures\\6HUP\\6HUP Entire ECD\\6HUP ECD GABA\\PYTHON COPY OF DockThor 6HUP Entire ECD GABA"
test_file_name = "PYTHON COPY OF DockThor 6HUP Entire ECD GABA DockThor 6HUP Entire ECD GABA R 2.pdb" # this is the file I'm trying to make duplicates of per 10S data section

os.chdir(path)

empty_list = []
end_of_ligand_line_num_list = [0]
pathway_tree = os.walk(path)  # os.walk gives a 2D array of all the names directories, sub directories and folders.
missing_array = []
for subdir, dirs, files_in_directory in pathway_tree: # to activates os.walk() you have to have 3 iterator variables
    for file_names in files_in_directory: # file_names is the folder of a specific sub directory, in which files are actually contained
        if  ".pdb" in file_names and "PYTHON COPY OF DockThor 6HUP Entire ECD GABA EntireECDof6HUP.pdb" != file_names:
            os.chdir(subdir)
            with open(file_names,"r") as input:
                list_of_lines = input.readlines()
                keyphrase ="ENDMDL"
                for Model_line_number, line in enumerate(list_of_lines, 0):
                    if keyphrase in line:
                        Model_line_number = int(Model_line_number)
                        end_of_ligand_line_num_list.append(Model_line_number)
                        for i in range(0 , len(end_of_ligand_line_num_list) - 1):
                            empty_list.append(list_of_lines[end_of_ligand_line_num_list[i] : end_of_ligand_line_num_list[i+1]    ] )

    no_duplicates = []
    [no_duplicates.append(d) for d in empty_list if d not in no_duplicates]

    for file_lines in no_duplicates:
        for chars in file_lines:
            with open("PYTHON COPY OF DockThor 6HUP Entire ECD GABA EntireECDof6HUP_COPYFORPYTHONDOCKTHORTEST.pdb","a") as output:
                output.write(chars)
        print(file_lines)
```

Comment: I really appreciate help from anyone, I'm just learning as I encounter real life occurences of me needing a set of code. Yes, I want to cut the huge file into smaller files. Each smaller file I want to append (that is, add to the bottom of another file previously written).

Comment: to a file I call "Structure" I need to make files that contain Structure + Section 1,  Structure + Section 2,  Structure + Section 3,  Structure + Section 4,   Structure + Section 5,  Structure + Section 6, Structure + Section 7, Structure + Section 8,  Structure + Section 9, Structure + Section 10. Problem is, I need to find a way to do this 24 or more of these "huge files" (what I called ``10S`` files). Once I create my appended duplicates, I need to figure out a way to name them based upon what section I appended to the duplicate.